# Why does the databinding between my WPF TextBox and Slider controls stop working when their tab is removed and re-added during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, slider

I have a WPF application which has several tabs. In one tab I have a silder and a textbox which are combined through binding:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderVol, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.125,0.615" />
<Slider  Delay="600" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" Value="{Binding Path=Volume, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"   Name="SliderVol"  Width="354" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="1" />
```

So far everything works fine when I start my app. In the textbox I always see the current value.

When I remove the tab during runtime and later add it again during runtime then the textbox is empty. Is there anything I have to do to re-initialize the controls?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the tab at all? Wouldn't simply hiding it be an option?

Comment: Your output window will often have useful messages about errors that occur during runtime from the xaml side of things.  What messages are you seeing there?

Comment: Basically: binding from one UI element to another is a bad idea. Since your question does not include a good [mcve] showing exactly what you're doing, no good answer can be provided. But: you should use view model objects to mediate bound data, and if you are using a `TabControl`, you should use data binding to a collection to define the tabs which exist. If you work with the WPF binding system as intended, these kinds of problems just don't happen.

Comment: Hiding the tab would be my prefered option but I haven't found out how to do that.

Comment: `Visibility="Collapsed"`?